# A chart with a single number using Kusto Query Language

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a simple Kusto request, something like the following:

```
customMetrics
    | where timestamp > ago(10m)
    | where name == "Custom metric number one"
    | summarize sum(value)
```

Obviously, the result of this query is a single number.

I would like to pin this request to a dashboard, so the tile will look like a card having a title/subtitle and the number retrieving as the result of the Kusto request. Firstly, I tried to use "render" operator, but it can draw either a chart or a simple unformatted table. I tried to use "render card", but ApplicationInsights answered that "We currently don't support 'card' visualization type."

Is there any other possibility to create the desired tile with a single number on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just pin the table query result:

```
customMetrics
    | where timestamp > ago(10m)
    | where name == "Custom metric number one"
    | summarize sum(value)
```

results in

[image]

It is probably the closest to a card you can do at the moment

There is another option as well, you can add a [Markdown tile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-markdown-tile), it can point to a url containing Markdown content so you might be able to create something that periodically updates a certain MD file and show that on the dashboard. You can leverage the [Application Insights API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) to get the value you want and have an azure function generate the markdown.

Another option, if you have access to [Power Bi](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/), is to create a Power Bi report that you share with external stakeholders/non developers.When going that direction you can use all the rich visuals Power Bi provides in combination with data from Application Insights, including [cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-types-for-reports-and-q-and-a#cards-single-number). See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi)

Comment: I was considering the possibility to pin the table. Actually, another way to do this is to use "render table" at the end of the query. But this is apropriate solution when you create a dashboard for internal use only, not when the dashboars will be shown for clients and/or management. The way with request to AppInsights API seems too complex and resource-consuming. Anyway, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @OleksiiSerik Now knowing you want to share the data with other stakeholders, I've added another option that might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @PeterBons. I've heard about Power BI a lot of good stuff, and your recommendation forces me to investigate this option more thoroughly. Seems, there is no way to reach the desired result using only Azure native functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Or use grafana? There’s a manager instance in azure albeit still in preview.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).